# How to merge stdin and stdout from providers.exec?

Tags: gradle

I migrate my build to a cache-configuration compatible way to execute external processes (it's a [`providers.exec`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:external_processes)).

Previously to merge stdin and stdout into one stream I used the following approach:

```kotlin
ByteArrayOutputStream().use {
    val execResult = exec {
        commandLine(*args)
        isIgnoreExitValue = true
        standardOutput = it // <----
        errorOutput = it // <----
    }
    return CommandExecutionResult(exitCode = execResult.exitValue, consoleOutput = it.toString())
}
```

Unfortunately, this will not work with `providers.exec` API.
The same attempt to redirect output throws "[Standard streams cannot be configured for exec output provider](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/d55c486870a0dc6f6278f53d21381396d0741c6e/platforms/core-configuration/model-core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/provider/sources/process/ProviderCompatibleBaseExecSpec.java#L47-L50)":

```kotlin
ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
    val execResult = providers.exec {
        commandLine(*args)
        isIgnoreExitValue = true
        standardOutput = outputStream
        errorOutput = outputStream
    }
    return CommandExecutionResult(exitCode = execResult.result.get().exitValue, consoleOutput = outputStream.toString())
}
```

How can I get a full console output (both stdin and stdout) from `providers.exec`?